# Formatted text field to take only time in the format '00:00:00'

Tags: java, jdbc

I am trying to write pre initial code to set formatted time and another to take date in the format  date, I am doing Human resource  application and I want to calculate over time based on attendance using MySQL database.

```
try {
    Date date = new Date();
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat(" HH:mm:ss");
    String dateString = formatter.format(date);
    jFormattedTextField1 = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter(" ##:##:##"));
} catch (Exception ex) {
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a SimpleDateFormat the set the text of the textfield with a time

```
Date date = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
String dateString = formatter.format(date);
formatText = new JFormattedTextField(createFormatter("##:##:##"));
formatText.setColumns(8);
formatText.setText(dateString);
```

If you need to get the date value of the input text, just parse it.

```
   Date date;
   try {
       date = formatter.parse(formatText.getText());
   } catch (ParseException ex) {
       ...
   }
```

Comment: thank you but I want it to force time date from the start .

Comment: I Editted, now your Textfield is set with current time from the beginning

Comment: Thank you very much I did find the answer I am seeking

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
ft = new JFormattedTextField (new MaskFormatter ("##:##:##"));

}
catch (java.text.ParseException e){

}
```

Navigated to code and set the pre initial code as the one above